# Duplicate window across monitors

Tags: windows-xp, window, duplicate, projector

I have a notebook with a projector attached. Normally I would set my the desktop to extend to the projector screen in Window's settings. I'm required to type something which should be seen by the audience. The projection is behind me so it's a bit tedious to type without seeing actually what I type.

All other windows should not be duplicated therefore the "duplicate the screen" option is not an option for me.

Is there any kind of software available with duplicates the window so I could put one of them on the projector screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) will do exactly what you want with its [mirroring feature](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/tour/mirroring.asp). It's available for for Windows 8, 7, Vista and XP.

For any OS X users that might stumble upon this, there's [DuplicateWindows](http://www.fabiancanas.com/Projects/DuplicateWindows/).

Comment: UltraMon sounds promising, I'll report back (and of course accept if it works)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be dependent on your laptop and video drivers, but most of them offer a "mirror" mode that will display the same image on both your laptop screen and the external monitor.  You'll have to dig around the Display Properties Control Panel (Go to the Settings Tab, you'll probably have to click "Advanced").

One thing to keep in mind: You can really only run in resolutions that both monitors support.  This almost always means lowering your laptop's panel to the projector's resolution.  However, when you need that functionality it's a minor setback.

Also, I believe that Windows 7 has this functionality built in as an extension to the multimon support.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention in my question that I need one window *not* to be shown to the audience. Therefore this is not a possibility for me.

Comment: You'll want to edit your question to add that requirement then, so anyone else who comes along sees it.  Not everyone reads all the comments.

Comment: Did this already.

Answer (score 0):

With most notebooks you can also toggle between selections of display modes by pressing the Function and F8 key together.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following information at this [link](http://www.ehow.com/how_5924857_mirror-monitors-xp.html).

> 1.Connect the second display to the computer while it is turned off. Turn
>   the computer on and allow Windows to
>   load.
>
> 2.Right-click an open area of the desktop, and click "Properties." This
>   brings up the display properties for
>   your system.
>
> 3.Click the "Settings" tab.
>
> 4.Remove the check from the box labeled "Extend my Windows desktop
>   onto this monitor."
>
> 5.Click "OK." The second monitor will immediately begin to display exactly
>   what is shown on the primary monitor.

Hope this helps. If you need any more help, comment back!